# How do I pass data into an Adaptive Card?

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic, adaptive-cards

I have a Microsoft Teams bot that sends out Adaptive Cards. I want to dynamically fill those with data (for example pictures). To do so I have 2 different JSON files. One with the layout of the card and one with the data.
How can I link those 2 files? How does the layout file know where to get the data from? I'm new to this and a bit lost ^^'

This is the layout code:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Hello ${name}!"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4"
}
```

This is my code for the data JSON:

```
{
     "name": "Cute Name"
}
```

This is how I render the card:

```
const rawDynamicGalleryCard = require("./adaptiveCards/dynamicGallery.json");

//show dynamic gallery card
switch (txt) {
   case "dynamic": {
   const card = cardTools.AdaptiveCards.declare(rawDynamicGalleryCard).render();
   await context.sendActivity({
     attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)],
   });
}
```

If I run the bot and type the keyword I get this:
[Bot Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRJeq.png)

Comment: Is `dynamicGallery.json` the name of either the "layout code" or the "data JSON", or some other schema? Could you include the filenames for both of those JSON snippets?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/#javascript-example) suggests the [adaptivecards-templating](https://npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-templating) package:

```
const ACData = require("adaptivecards-templating");

const dynamicGalleryTemplate = require("./adaptiveCards/dynamicGallery.json");
const dynamicGalleryData = require("./adaptiveCards/data.json");

const template = new ACData.Template(dynamicGalleryTemplate);

const card = template.expand({
    $root: dynamicGalleryData
});

// Now you have an AdaptiveCard ready to render!
```

(This assumes that `dynamicGallery.json` is your "layout code" above, and I made a total guess as to where your data json is.)

Answer (score -1):

The `render` method takes in the data as argument. Define the data like so:

```
const data = {"name": "Cute Name"};
```

then pass it

```
const card = AdaptiveCards.declare(rawDynamicGalleryCard).render(data);
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation validating this. Which platform is this for?

Comment: You can find this in the [source code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/blob/c6f5fa837e2262fd2be71c1c1450af60e785a175/packages/adaptivecards-tools-sdk/src/AdaptiveCards.ts#L33C3-L42C9)

Comment: I believe that code is how MS Teams handles their own rendering of adaptive cards. The actual rendering with data in JS looks uses their [templating lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-templating#usage). They import this lib in [line 5](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/blob/c6f5fa837e2262fd2be71c1c1450af60e785a175/packages/adaptivecards-tools-sdk/src/AdaptiveCards.ts#L5) of the link you pasted.